# Flutter Repaint vs Rebuild

Tags: flutter, riverpod

Im trying to understand flutter internal rebuild and repaint mechanism and stumbled upon the following questions:

1. What is the difference between a repaint and a rebuild?
2. Does a rebuild always imply a repaint?
3. Which action is considered as CPU intensive and could be optimized?

All these questions originated when I was trying to understand how flutter marks widgets as dirty when an InheritedWidget notify changes or when calling setState.
Correct me if wrong, but what I understand is that when one of these two actions occur, Flutter marks the widgets and all its descendants as dirty [updateChild](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Element/updateChild.html) method for each one of them.

The method can be summarized in this steps:

```dart
Element? updateChild(Element? child, Widget? newWidget, Object? newSlot) {
  if (newWidget == null) {
    return null;
  }

  final Element newChild;
  if (child != null) {
    if (child.widget == newWidget) { // 1
      newChild = child;
    } else if (Widget.canUpdate(child.widget, newWidget)) { // 2
      child.update(newWidget);
      newChild = child;
    } else {
      deactivateChild(child);
      newChild = inflateWidget(newWidget, newSlot); // 3
    }
  }

  return newChild;
}
```

What I understand is that if the widget is const and condition number 1 is met the widget wont be rebuilt nor repainted (this is what Riverpod helps with). If condition 2 is met, child.update is called with the new widget but all this function does is `_widget = newWidget;`, so it seems no rebuilt or repaint here. Finally, if neither condition 1 or 2 are met, step 3 comes in and calls inflateWidget. This ends up calling widget.createElement. What happens here? Will this create also a RenderObject and trigger a widget build and paint? This is where I get lost.